# Instantly Changing database entry when editing an input field manually and also with + and - buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm did find a library several months ago but am unable to find it now, the aim of what I am trying to do is having input fields with + and - buttons either side and when the input changes value for it to update the database with the change instantly.

[image]

- The **minus** button would **decrease** the input field by x (1 in this example)
- The **plus** button would **increase** the input field by x (1 in this example)
- The input field should be able to be edited manually rather than being "locked"

I did it the manual way as you can see below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.add').on('click', function() {
    var $counter = $(this).closest('p').find('.counter');
    var currentVal = parseInt($counter.val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      $counter.val(currentVal + 1);
    }
  });
  $('.minus').on('click', function() {
    var $counter = $(this).closest('p').find('.counter');
    var currentVal = parseInt($counter.val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
      $counter.val(currentVal - 1);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#inputcounter {
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/olbGCog.png" width="20" height="20" id="minus" class="minus" />
    <input type="text" value="5" id="inputcounter" class="counter" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yZHYjWw.png" width="20" height="20" id="add" class="add" />
  </p>
</body>
```

## More thorough one: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls3rhphr/

How can I then use the above to instantly edit a database entry so when the the input changes it updates the database without requiring me to click an update/submit button?

Comment: You can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/yzg1fLf8/2/).

Comment: short answer ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @LoganWayne he has that part already

Comment: @Dagon Oh I'm sorry. I'll try to post an answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @Ryflex - is there an ID associated with the input fields? Or is it just a single row in your table?

Comment: @LoganWayne Yes, each input is on it's own row in a table and the ID associated with each field can be found by the table row via as seen: `<tr id="mem-1">`, `<tr id="mem-2">`... etc

Comment: How do you set the value of the `id` tag? Can you update it in your post? I think it's coming from your database and you show it like this `<tr id="mem-'.$id.'">`

Comment: @LoganWayne See: http://jsfiddle.net/Ls3rhphr/ It's much more thorough

Comment: @Ryflex - so... Your `id ` tag is fix to `mem-N`. It is not coming from your database? Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dagon suggested in the comments, lets use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

We can use a function so we don't have to rewrite the Ajax script when the value changes.

```
function updateNumber(id, newvalue){

    $.ajax({ /* START AJAX */
        type: "POST", /* METHOD TO PASS DATA */
        url: "update.php", /* PAGE WHERE TO PROCESS THE DATA; YOU CAN CHANGE THIS DIRECTORY DEPENDING ON WHERE YOU WANT TO SAVE YOUR UPDATE PAGE */
        data: {"id": id, "newvalue": newvalue} /* DATA TO BE PROCESSED */
    }); /* END OF AJAX */

}
```

Lets assume also that you set an id to your row (*as you stated in the comment, that you store id in your `<tr>`*). We will add a new tag - `data-artid` where we set the id **only**:

```
<tr id="mem-1" data-artid="1">
```

We can just call the function above in your script below:

```
$(function() {
  $('.add').on('click', function() {
    var $counter = $(this).closest('p').find('.counter');
    var currentVal = parseInt($counter.val());
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-artid'); /* GET THE ID */
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      $counter.val(currentVal + 1);
      newvalue = currentVal + 1; /* STORE THE NEW VALUE */
      updateNumber(id, newvalue); /* CALL THE updateNumber FUNCTION */
    }
  });
  $('.minus').on('click', function() {
    var $counter = $(this).closest('p').find('.counter');
    var currentVal = parseInt($counter.val());
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-artid'); /* GET THE ID */
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
      $counter.val(currentVal - 1);
      newvalue = currentVal - 1; /* STORE THE NEW VALUE */
      updateNumber(id, newvalue); /* CALL THE updateNumber FUNCTION */
    }
  });
});
```

Now, we have to create the `update.php`. This is where we will update the data in your database.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE tableName SET inputcounter = ? WHERE id = ?"); /* JUST CHANGE THE TABLE NAME AND COLUMN NAME TO YOURS */
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $_POST["newvalue"], $_POST["id"]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```